# InAppPurchase erreur

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

Ionic:

```
@ionic/cli: "^6.10.0",
Ionic Framework               : "@ionic/angular": "^5.1.1"
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.13
@angular-devkit/schematics: "^9.1.7",
@angular/cli: "^9.1.7",
@ionic/angular-toolkit: "~2.0.0",
```

System:

NodeJS  : v12.14.0
npm     : 6.13.4
OS      : macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3
Xcode   : Xcode 12.4 Build version 12D4e
In the need to activate in-app-purchase in an Ionic/iOS app, I built my product in App Store Connect for test.In the need to activate in-app-purchase in an Ionic/iOS app, I built my product in App Store Connect for test.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcS7E.png)
I developed an Angular / Ionic application with online payment and I created an ios application and when I sent it for verification it was rejected by Apple requiring to integrate "in-app-purchase", that is is why I used the Plugin "In-App-Purchase2" to manage the purchase But when I try to access the package I created, XCode launches the following logger: "Undefined" or nothing display .
I don't understand why I can't find my product (my product list is empty), I noticed that there is no connection between my app and AppleStoreConnect ..
Could you help me find out if the method I am using was good and why it is not working well.
My Code :
[Pasted Graphic 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cefbf.png)

[Pasted Graphic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnFqH.png)

Log Xcode
[Loadina network plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQCbC.png)

Applications Agreement is signed
[Capture d’écran, le 2021-06-11 à 12 24 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjozH.png)

Ps: i tested it in simulator

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - post as text here.

Comment: I do not know Ionic but I do know IAP has to be tested on a real device, it does not work in the simulator

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Juliana welcome to the community! Lets help you with a snippet code. You need to be sure the Store is ready before ask to handle the products, and use NgZone to get the products data.

```
  constructor(private store: InAppPurchase2){
    this.productId = 'my_product_name'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.setupPurchase();
      }
    });
  }

  setupPurchase() {    
    this.store.verbosity = this.store.DEBUG;
    this.store.register({
      id: this.productId,
      type: this.store.NON_CONSUMABLE
    });
    console.log('verbosity  ', JSON.stringify(this.store.verbosity));
    this.store.ready(() => {   
      this.registerHandlersForPurchase(this.productId);
    });
    // refresh/store purchase
    this.store.refresh();
  }

  registerHandlersForPurchase(productId) {
    // Approved
    this.store.when(productId).approved((product: IAPProduct) => {
      console.log('Approved  ', JSON.stringify(product));
      // Product Finish
      product.finish();
    });

    // User closed the native purchase dialog
    this.store.when(this.productId).cancelled((product) => {
      console.error('User Canceled! ', product);
    });

    this.store.refresh();
    
    this.product = this.store.get(this.productId);
    if (!!this.product.id && !!this.product.priceMicros) {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        // Use on HTML view to show the products
        this.displayProduct = this.product;
      });
    }
    console.log('Handlers produto  ', JSON.stringify(this.product));
    // Track all store errors
    this.store.error( (err) => {
      console.error('Store Error ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  }
```

Please, adapt it to your code and run on native device. You will see the console.log() on debugging with the errors and status of the products.